# PostgreSQL: displaying cross-references inside a table in a user friendly way

Tags: postgresql, cross-reference

I have a table which contains rows of account verifications. One account can have one or more rows related to it, depending on how many attempts it took for it to verify.

In each entry there's reference which tells me whether a specific unique parameter of that account appears in other account verifications. The problem is that the reference can also point to the same account as well which is of no use for me. I want to find accounts which share a unique parameter - i.e. where the reference points to different accounts.

I don't have the unique parameter in the table, that would've made it a lot easier.

Here's an example (ordered by time of creation desc):

```
| verification_id | account_id   | reference |
|-----------------|--------------|-----------|
|       4a        |      4       |     4a    |
|       3a        |      3       |    1a,3a  |
|       2b        |      2       |    2a,2b  |
|       2a        |      2       |     2a    |
|       1a        |      1       |     1a    |
```

I'm not interested in the fact that the reference points out that a unique parameter appears in both 2a and 2b verifications, because they belong to the same account.

I'm interested in the fact that a unique parameter appears both in account_id 1 and 3, as pointed out by the reference cell (i.e. 1a,3a).

This is the result I'm looking for:

```
| account_id  | connected to |
|-------------|--------------|
|      1      |      3       |
|      3      |      1       |
```

Or even just the first row would be enough.

Hope I did a good job explaining the problem and the outcome.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values like that. Do you have a chance to fix that broken data model?

Comment: What is the datatype of the `reference` column?

Comment: What if `references` contains 10 different values? What exactly is the output you want then?

Comment: > What is the datatype of the reference column?
JSON array

Comment: > What if references contains 10 different values? What exactly is the output you want then?

Good question. I would want them centralised around one main account_id. Gotta, say, you stumped me a bit with this question.

Comment: > You shouldn't be storing comma separated values like that. Do you have a chance to fix that broken data model?

Sorry, that's just a simplified example. The cell contains a JSON array.

Comment: Mike's answer got me a lot closer to what I needed to do. Thank you @MikeOrganek

Answer (score 0):

Join on inequality for `account_id` and `verification_id` and then test for array overlap with `&&`:

```
select a.account_id, b.account_id as connected_to
  from verification a
       join verification b
         on a.account_id != b.account_id
        and a.verification_id != b.verification_id
        and string_to_array(a.reference, ',') && 
              string_to_array(b.reference, ',');
```

[Working fiddle here.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3pJJbwxAkzKUbegZa6PtHk/0)